Which particular characters will the Autocad MText editor accept as a valid bulleted character?
Can someone tell me which particular characters will the Autocad MText editor accept as a valid bulleted character?
I thought maybe Autocad was using the standard Unicode character ranges as the mechanism but unfortunately not. For example, Autocad will only allow a sub-set of characters in the unicode Latin Extended-D range (A789..A7FF)
I am working in Python on this project. But VBA or Lisp solutions would be welcomed.
Michelle

By default AutoCAD will use character 183 (U+00B7) to represent a bullet point in MText, with embedded formatting to use the Symbol font, e.g.:
{\\fSymbol|b0|i0|c2|p18;·}
Where embedded formatting codes are concerned, you may also find this reference useful:
https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-7D8BB40F-5C4E-4AE5-BD75-9ED7112E5967

True enough that is the default; however our company mandates that General Notes be imported from a Word document. This presents compatibility issues and we must be careful about which bullet chars we use in Word; hence the question.
In terms of embedded formatting codes; a much more complete reference can be found here:
link
